# Excepción y expresiones

Tags: java, regex

Realizo una serie de **validaciones** para que en mi formulario en `Java` sólo se permitan introducir datos correctos y lógicos.

Datos a insertar:

```
- potencia (int)
- consumo (double)
```

Código **Validaciones.java** (expresiones regulares):

```
public static boolean validarConsumo(String consumo){
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+([,\\.][0-9]*)?$");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(consumo);
        if (mat.matches()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean validarPotencia(String potencia){
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{1,3}$");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(potencia);
        int n = Integer.parseInt(potencia);
        if ((mat.matches()) && (n>39 && n<501)) { //>=40 && <=500
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Código **Formulario.java** (JFrame) **[ACTUALIZADO]**

```
private void button_OKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        //Atributos generales para todo tipo de vehículos.
        String bastidor = textfield_bastidor.getText();
        int marca = combobox_marcas.getSelectedIndex() + 1;
        String matricula = textfield_matricula.getText();
        String modelo = (String) combobox_modelos.getSelectedItem();
        String color = (String) combobox_color.getSelectedItem();
        int potencia = Integer.parseInt(textfield_potencia.getText());
        double consumo = Double.parseDouble(textfield_consumo.getText());
        String descripcion = textfield_descripcion.getText();
        try {
            if (!Validaciones.validarBastidor(bastidor)) {
                throw new Exception("Formato de bastidor incorrecto.");
            }
            if (!Validaciones.validarMatricula(matricula)) {
                throw new Exception("Formato de matrícula incorrecta.");
            }
            if (!Validaciones.validarDescripcion(descripcion)) {
                throw new Exception("Formato de descripción incorrecta.");
            }

            if (!Validaciones.validarPotencia(String.valueOf(potencia))) {
                throw new Exception("Formato de potencia incorrecta.");
            }
            if (!Validaciones.validarConsumo(String.valueOf(consumo))) {
                throw new Exception("Formato de consumo incorrecto.");
            }

            //Excepción por si el valor introducido no es un entero.
            potencia = 0;
            try {
                potencia = Integer.parseInt(textfield_potencia.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe_potencia) {
                nfe_potencia.getMessage();
            }

            //Excepción por si el valor introducido no es un double.
            consumo = 0.0;
            try {
                consumo = Double.parseDouble(textfield_consumo.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe_consumo) {
                nfe_consumo.getMessage();
            }

            //Evitamos formatear la fecha cuando el valor del campo textfield_fecha_fabricacion sea nulo o vacío.
            Date f = null;
            if (!textfield_fecha_fabricacion.getText().equals("")) {
                String fecha_fabricacion = textfield_fecha_fabricacion.getText();
                //Damos formato a la fecha a insertar. Por ejemplo: 2010/10/10.
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                try {
                    //Convertimos a Date la fecha recogida como String.
                    f = sdf.parse(fecha_fabricacion);
                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Alta_vehiculo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

            //Comprobamos que están todos los datos insertados...
            if (!textfield_bastidor.getText().isEmpty() && !textfield_consumo.getText().isEmpty()
                    && !textfield_descripcion.getText().isEmpty() && !textfield_fecha_fabricacion.getText().isEmpty()
                    && !textfield_matricula.getText().isEmpty() && !textfield_potencia.getText().isEmpty()
                    && !textfield_precio.getText().isEmpty() && !textfield_precio.getText().isEmpty()) {
                //Comprobamos si el bastidor no existe en la base de datos...
                if (!Conexiones.cargar_bastidores().contains(textfield_bastidor.getText())) {
                    //Depende de qué radiobutton pulsemos...
                    if (radiobutton_alquiler.isSelected()) {
                        //Excepción por si el valor introducido no es un double.
                        double precio = 0.0;
                        try {
                            precio = Double.parseDouble(textfield_precio.getText());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe_precio) {
                            nfe_precio.getMessage();
                        }
                        boolean disponible = checkbox_disponible.isSelected();
                        Vehiculo va = new Vehiculo_Alquiler(precio, true, bastidor, color, matricula, modelo,
                                marca, potencia, consumo, f, descripcion);
                        //Llamamos al método alta_vehiculo() para insertar el vehículo en la base de datos.
                        Conexiones.alta_vehiculo(va);
                    } else {
                        //Excepción por si el valor introducido no es un double.
                        double precio = 0.0;
                        try {
                            precio = Double.parseDouble(textfield_precio.getText());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe_precio) {
                            nfe_precio.getMessage();
                        }
                        Vehiculo vc = new Vehiculo_Compra(precio, null, bastidor, color, matricula, modelo,
                                marca, potencia, consumo, f, descripcion);
                        //Llamamos al método alta_vehiculo() para insertar el vehículo en la base de datos.
                        Conexiones.alta_vehiculo(vc);
                        dispose();
                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡¡¡Este bastidor ya EXISTE en la base de datos!!!", "ATENCIÓN ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    textfield_bastidor.requestFocus();
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡¡¡Debes rellenar TODOS los campos!!!", "ATENCIÓN ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "ATENCIÓN ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

**Mi problema es:**

-Si dejo los campos vacíos salta la excepción. NO funciona.

-Si inserto texto ("debe saltar error") en los campos, salta la excepción. NO funciona.

ERROR:

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "debe saltar error"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
```

Comment: No puedes convertir una cadena de letras o un valor vacío a un valor numérico . (*Int* , *Double*,etc) , por eso te arroja dicha Exception. podrías enviarle a tus métodos validar el *getText()* de tus TextField directamente. Realizando  antes la validación que no sea un valor null o vacío (" ").

Answer (score 2):

Ambos métodos

```
public static boolean validarConsumo(String consumo){
```

y

```
public static boolean validarPotencia(String potencia){
```

deben recibir un valor String numerico ya que internamente realizan una conversión, si los valores que reciben no son númericos, se obtiene el error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "....

Antes de llamar los métodos podrías validar si la cadena es númerica mediante un método por ejemplo:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str){  
  try  
  {  
    double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
  }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){  
    return false;  
  }  
  return true;  
}
```

Realizarías la validación para determinar si es un valor númerico antes de llamar los métodos:

```
if(isNumeric(valorConsumo)){
   // llama validarConsumo(String valorConsumo)
}

if(isNumeric(valorPotencia)){
   // llama validarPotencia(String valorPotencia)
}
```

---

**Actualización:**
Tu código podría ser reducido a (usando el método `isNumeric()` sugerido):

```
private void button_OKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

int potencia;    
double consumo;

if(isNumeric(textfield_potencia.getText()){
    potencia = Integer.parseInt(textfield_potencia.getText());
}else{
    //Excepción por si el valor introducido no es un entero.
        potencia = 0;
}


if(isNumeric(textfield_consumo.getText()){
    consumo = Double.parseDouble(textfield_consumo.getText());
}else{
 //Excepción por si el valor introducido no es un double.
        consumo = 0.0;
}


        //Aqui resto del código (inserciones en la base de datos, actualizaciones de tablas, etc...).
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "ATENCIÓN ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sigo teniendo el mismo problema. Acabo de EDITAR mi código. ¿Cómo sería la solución?

Comment: He agregado una actualización, tu método puede ser reducido mucho más, con eso no debes tener problema.

Comment: Me sigue sin funcionar. Actualizo con mi código actual.

Comment: @omaza1990 ......... realizaste lo que comento en mi actualización??? usaste el método que sugiero isNumeric() ???

Comment: Si, y error. No se porque me sigue dando el mismo error. Intenta con mi código completo encontrar donde esta el error porque me vuelvo loco llevo todo el día para esta "chorrada". Seguro que es un error leve.

Comment: Acabo de ver tu código no veo en la actualización el método public static boolean isNumeric(String str){  , agrega la actualización por favor, el error es facil de evitar pero veo tienes otro código.

Comment: Ya me funciona sin el método isNumeric() pero me gustaría incluirlo pero no sé dónde ni cómo. Tengo un caos ahora mismo...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52033/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-elenasys).

Comment: hehe, ok que bueno si quieres agrega el código y con el método que menciono lo puedes reducir.

Answer (score 2):

El código de tu clase `Formulario` empieza con:

```
   int potencia = Integer.parseInt(textfield_potencia.getText());
   double consumo = Double.parseDouble(textfield_consumo.getText());
```

Ambos métodos tratan de convertir el texto ingresado a un valor numérico y en el caso de tus ejemplos tiran un `NumberFormatException`. En tus ejemplos dados nunca llegas al código con la validación, entonces tu código hace exactamente lo ue se podría esperar. La validación entonces debería hacerse antes de usar `parseInt` o `parseDouble`, o deberías simplemente tratar el parse y luego en la validación comprobar si los valores se encuentran dentro de los limites.

En la validación del consumo solamente compruebas si el consumo es un numérico. Los métodos `parseInt` y `parseDouble` ya hacen eso para ti sin mas código propio.
En la potencia más encima compruebas si el valor es dentro de un rango permitido.

Recomiendo lo siguiente para la validación:

```
private void button_OKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try{
        potencia = Integer.parseInt(textfieldPotencia.getText());
        if (!validatePotencia(potencia)) throw new NumberFormatException("fuera de rango");
        // aquí tiene que ser NumberFormatException, no NumberformatException
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "ATENCIÓN ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }

    try{
        consumo = Integer.parseInt(textfieldPotencia.getText());
        // consumo no necesita cumplir con mas que ser un `Double` valido;
        // aquí lo mismo
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "ATENCIÓN ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }

    // luego el código para procesar los datos ingresados;
}
```

con el método para validar potencia:

```
public static boolean validarPotencia(int potencia){
    return (potencia>39 && potencia<501);
}
```

Menos código, mas simple, mas obvio para otros.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a primero hacer las validaciones y luego las conversiones? Es decir (saldrá todo de seguido pero espero que se entienda): int potencia = Integer.parseInt(textfield_potencia.getText());
        double consumo = Double.parseDouble(textfield_consumo.getText());
        try {
            if (!Validaciones.validarPotencia(String.valueOf(potencia))) {
                throw new Exception("Formato incorrecto.");
            }
            if (!Validaciones.validarConsumo(String.valueOf(consumo))) {
                throw new Exception("Formato incorrecto.");
            }

Comment: Te agrego la explicación a la respuesta.

Comment: Lo siento pero no me funciona, edito.

Comment: Hola, lo usaste tal cual copiado? Recién me di cuenta que tengo un lapso de ortografía en el nombre de una clase en el codigo, pero si lo usaste en algun IDE te lo debería haber reclamado. Te lo edito.

Comment: Lo use en el IDE de Netbeans pero me sigue dando el mismo error de For input string: "....

Comment: En la `NumberFormatException`, que exacto te muestra como dato ingresado? Podrias compartir el ultimo stacktrace?

Comment: https://s30.postimg.org/57vff1lwx/image.png Imagen del error. Arranco la aplicación, entro al formulario y sin rellenar ningun campo pulso "OK" y me salta ese error, cuando debería saltarme el mensaje de "Debe rellenar todos los campos".

Comment: Tu error es más arriba en el código. En la excepción sale Alta_vehiculo.java:429, tu muestras el código de 452 siguiente. Parece que usas `parseInt()` en otra parte ya, pero fuera de un try/catch

Comment: Solucionado. Sí ahí estaba el error.